# Calculating Hard Disk Capacity

Tags: disk, diskspace

Consider a disk with the following characteristics:
Number of surface 16
Number of sectors / cylinder 4096
Number of tracks per surface 2048
Number of bytes per sector 512

1) How many patters does the disk have ?
I got:  number of surfaces / 2 
            = 8

2)How many sectors per tack ?
I got:  Number tracks per cylinder =  tracks per surface * surfaces
            = 2048 * 16 
            = 32, 768
Number of sectors per track = number of tracks per cylinder / number of sectors per cylinder

```
        = 32, 768 / 4096 
        = 8
```

3) What is the total size of this disk
I got : Total size = cylinders * surfaces * sectors per track * 512 bytes

```
    = 32,768 * 16 * 8 * 512  
    = 2, 147, 483, 648 bytes  
    = 2, 097, 152 Mb  
    = 2, 048 Gb
```

The thing is, I dont know if this is right solution

Comment: [Online Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/mediasizecalc.html)

Comment: Is this perhaps a homework assignment? It looks like you're asking us to spot check your work. As it stands, it's off topic for Stack Overflow (there's no programming question here), and I'm not quite comfortable migrating it to a sister site.

Comment: wrong answer, check solution provided by +RollingBoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to multiplier the number of cylinders, heads and sectors, so you'll get the number of blocks, multiplier it for 512 and you got the answer, I think that is it...

Comment: answer is wrong, check solution that +RollingBoy has given

Answer (score 6):

```
Question2:
Number of surface 16 -> a cylinder consists of 16 tracks.
Number of sectors / cylinder == 4096
Then sectors per track = 4096/16 = 256

Question3:
16 * 2048 * 256 * 512 = 4294967296
```

Comment: 1) **Each platter has two surface . no of surface 16/2 = 8 platter**

2) **Number of sectors per track = no of sectors per cylinder/16 ie,
4096/16 = 256**

3) **Total storage = 16(surface)*256(sector)*2048(cylinder)*512(bytes)**
= 4GB